# The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'. error

Tags: flutter, dart, android-alertdialog

I am creating **Alert dialog widget** but it is giving this error.
Where am I going wrong please help

*error: The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.*

CODE:

```
`IconButton _iconButton() => IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        **
> showDialog(
> **context: context,====>>>> error is shown here**
> builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: AppBar(
              title: Text("are you sure you want to delete"),
            ),
            content: Text(""),
            actions: [
              TextButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(Icons.playlist_add_check_circle_rounded),
                  label: Text("YES")),
              TextButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                  label: Text("CANCEL"))
            ],
          ),
        );**
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.ads_click));`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to use **_iconButton** as a function, do this:

```
IconButton _iconButton(BuildContext context) => IconButton( // ...
```

If instead you want to use it as a simple widget do this:

```
IconButton _iconButton = IconButton( // ...
```